# debug/optimize java application

Tags: java, debugging, maven

Is there any optimized and debug mode for a java code? Using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.3/gcc/Debugging-Options.html), it is possible to add debug symbols via `-g -ggdb` to the binary for debugging purposes and remove them by adding `-O` option to maximize the speed.

What about Java? I am using Maven (pom.xml). I can not find such option for Java

Comment: I don't understand the question. Java code can be debugged through any java debugging tool. And the JVM handles optimizations and whatnot. You'll have to elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java compiler options can be specified in the [Maven Compiler Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html). 
Example: excluding debug information, enabling optimization:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <debug>false</debug>
      <debuglevel>none</debuglevel>
      <optimize>true</optimize>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

A complete list of configuration options can be found [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html).

Comment: OK I see `<debug>false</debug>` and `<optimize>true</optimize>`.

Comment: The -o option in gcc enables compile-time optimizations (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html). For Maven, this corresponds to the <optimize> option. Java has less optimization options at compile time (such as inlining), but can optimize itself at runtime (Just-in-time compiler).

Comment: In each folder, there is a pom.xml file. Should I add `<debug>false</debug>` in all of them or just the root folder?